# How to populate a table with 1000 rows of sample data?

Tags: mysql, sql, populate

For the table bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    ModifiedDate datetime,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    EMail varchar(30),
    PhoneNumber varchar(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: For a thousand rows I would create a procedure with a loop containing an insert statement and some adjustable variables.

Comment: @P.Salmon can you be more specific? can you make the procedure for me?

Comment: For a thousand rows (well, 1024 rows) I would just do 10 inserts. It's surely at least as quick as writing a sproc

Answer (score 3):

You can write a query such as this:

```
INSERT INTO Persons(ModifiedDate, FirstName, LastName, EMail, PhoneNumber)
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()* 31536000) SECOND, -- random datetime up to -1 year
    CHAR(FLOOR(RAND() * 26)+ ASCII('A')),  -- random character between A-Z
    CHAR(FLOOR(RAND() * 26)+ ASCII('A')),
    CHAR(FLOOR(RAND() * 26)+ ASCII('a')),  -- random character between a-z
    CHAR(FLOOR(RAND() * 10)+ ASCII('0'))   -- random character between 0-9
FROM any_table_with_1000_rows
LIMIT 1000
```

Any table with 1000 rows could be used. If there isn't one, you can join a table having *n* rows with itself to get *n<sup>2</sup>* rows.

Comment: For T-SQL, I had to change the random datetime column to:
`DATEADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * -315576000), GETDATE()), -- random datetime up to -10 years`

Comment: @srsedate `RAND()` in TSQL will give you same value for every row inside one query!

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use https://www.mockaroo.com/ which is designed for that purpose. Create the columns you want and choose SQL as the output. It will make you a nice script.

You could also create an Excel spreadsheet to generate your SQL queries but it is a bit time consuming

Answer (score 2):

#### Execute the following query, it will insert 1000 dummy rows

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RowCount int = 1000,
            @Index int = 1

    WHILE (@Index <= @RowCount)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Persons (ID, ModifiedDate, FirstName, LastName, EMail, PhoneNumber)
                    VALUES (@Index, getdate(), 'FirstName' + CAST(@Index AS varchar(10)), 'LastName' + CAST(@Index AS varchar(10)), 'EMail' + CAST(@Index AS varchar(10)), CAST(@Index AS varchar(10)))
        SET @Index += 1
    END
END
```